# How can I Add Button action to an Area

Tags: validform

I'm using ValidForm Builder to build a complex form in PHP.
Am facing some issues using the framework... I want to make a Wizard form containing multiples hidden Area or FieldSet, those Area should have a clickable Buttons that will show the next Area after clicking.

This is an example of what am trying to do :

```
$profile_page = $objForm->addPage("profile_page", "Your Profile");// 1st page

$product_area = new Area("1 - Choose your product"); // 1st Area

// fields to be validated before showing the next Area, whene clicking on 
// the button 'Next'
$product_name = $product_area ->addField ....
$product_price = $product_area ->addField ....//
$product_type = $product_area ->addField ....//

$next_btn = new Button('Next'); // the Next button

// throw an error if its an Area object
$product_area ->addField($next_btn); // can't add a navigation Bouton !

$user_area = new Area("2 - Your Informations"); // 2nd Area 'hidden'

$user_firstname = $user_area->addField ....// 2nd Area fields
$user_lastname = $user_area->addField ....//
....
```

I can switch to the Fieldset but I can't  add actions or conditions between Buttons and Fieldset or Area object..

So how can I add a condition related to Button click , so if I clicked on specified Button it will show the next hidden Area after validating the current...

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ValidWizard there is no need to add the **next** or **previous** buttons and actions yourself. ValidWizard takes care of that for you.

You do need to add the validwizard.js file to your code.

Thanks to your question I discovered an issue with the page navigation and crated a pull request on [GitHub](https://github.com/validformbuilder/validformbuilder/pull/106). Once it has been added to the base code the page navigation will work as expected.

A very basic setup would be:

```
$objForm = new ValidWizard(
    "awesomeWizard",
    "Please fill out my cool wizard",
    "/stuff",
    array(
        "nextLabel" => "Next page",
        "previousLabel" => "Previous page"
    )
);

$objForm->addPage("firstPage", "First Page");

$objForm->addField(
    'name', 
    'Name', 
    ValidForm::VFORM_STRING,
    ["required" => true],
    ["required" => "This field is required"]
);

$objForm->addPage("secondPage", "Second Page");

$objForm->addField(
    'city', 
    'City', 
    ValidForm::VFORM_STRING,
    ["required" => true],
    ["required" => "This field is required"]
);

//*** Output submitted data or the form
if ($objForm->isSubmitted() && $objForm->isValid()) {
    $strOutput = $objForm->valuesAsHtml();
} else {
    $strOutput = $objForm->toHtml();
}

echo $strOutput;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you quick reply, but the main process I want to achieve is to  navigate between Areas  or Fields Inside the Wizard'Page itself, before going to the next Page.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to validate a specific section before going to the next, right? That's what the wizard functionality is for. 
Alternatively, you could hook into the `validate` method with JavaScript and use the optional selector to force validation within a specific Area.